# Comparing two arrays with loop does not show expected result C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to compare 2 Values from 2 different arrays.
If I try it with this method:

```
if (stockTest[1].getTestTitle() == products[8].getTitle())
    cout << " it works ";
```

It will display the " it works ".

If i try it with the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
  {
     if (stockTest[i].getTestTitle() == products[j].getTitle())
     {
        cout << stockTest[i].getTestTitle() << " is available ";
     }
     if (stockTest[i].getTestTitle() != products[j].getTitle())
     {
        cout << stockTest[j].getTestTitle() << " not available ";
     }
  }
}
```

It will only display one Value, that it is available and two that are not. The example above will be shown as not available.. what am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: is `getTestTitle()` and  `getTitle()` returning a string?

Comment: yes it is returning a string

Comment: what kind? std::string or char*?

Comment: @Taurus22: A `std::string` (which can be compared with `==`)? Or a C-style `char *` (which can't)? Or some other kind of string?

Comment: I'm getting them from an txt File if that helps

Comment: @Taurus22 No, it doesn't. Show us the definitions of `getTitle()` and `getTestTitle()`

Comment: string getTestTitle(); and string getTitle();

Comment: just because you don't know the answer it isn't a bad question (because of the bad votes) xP

Comment: @Taurus22  `If i try it with the loop:`  If that loop is in a separate program, then we don't know if the data is the same.  Write both tests in the *same* program, one after the other.  If item 1 compares equally to item 8 in that separate line of code, then in the loop, when `i == 1` and `j == 8`  then the "is available" **has** to be printed.

Comment: no its in the same program that's really strange i know..

Comment: @Taurus22 It cannot be the same program, unless after the first test, you're doing something with the data to alter it before you hit the looping part of the program.  Otherwise, no one would be able to write a program successfully if it's this unpredictable.

Comment: @Taurus22 Cannot duplicate the problem.  The program here works fine:  http://ideone.com/ljGJQi

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
    if (stockTest[i].getTestTitle() == products[j].getTitle()) {
      cout << stockTest[i].getTestTitle() << " is available ";
    }
    else {
      cout << stockTest[i].getTestTitle() << " not available ";
    }
  }
}
```

The 2 conditions complement each other logically, and so, an `if-else` is better and, in the second `cout`, `stockTest` had `j` as index instead of `i`.

Comment: that doesn't work either.. Now I'm getting a lot of outprints instead of only 3.

Comment: Can you clarify: what is the expected result?

Comment: it's to complex to explain everything, I will try it later again by myself, however thank you!